# Django - retrieve data for extend template

Tags: python, django

I have a base template in my app, and a Profile template with the user data, with a bunch of other pages that they can navigate through.
Every user has a market. I want to display the market name on every profile page, not bypassing every page a block tag.

**base.html**

```
<span class="title navbar-item">
    {% block market_name %}{% endblock %}
</span>
```

**every-profile-page.html**

```
{% block market_name %}{{market.name}}{% endblock market_name %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply implement this as:

```
<span class="title navbar-item">
    {% block market_name %}{{ market.name }}{% endblock %}
</span>
```

or if you never will overwrite it, just omit the block:

```
<span class="title navbar-item">
    {{ market.name }}
</span>
```

As long as every view passes a `market.name`, this is not a problem.

It might however be cumbersome to pass a market to every context. You can make use of a [*context processor* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext). You can implement such context processor in any app, for example:

```
# app/context_processors.py

def market(request):
    return {
        'market': …
    }
```

then you register the context processor in the `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py

# …

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # …
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # …
                'app.context_processors.market'
            ]
        }
        # …
    }
]
```

Comment: So easy! Thank you!